# Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#, .net, thread, stack

Esta dando esse erro:

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

na variável `qtde` ao adicioná-la na lista `desci`.

```
class descricaoo : IInstrucao
    {
        private string descricaobol;
        public descricaoo(int ibanco, int codigo, string descricaobol, int qtde)
        {
            this.descricaobol = descricaobol;
            List<IInstrucao> desci = new List<IInstrucao>();
            desci.Add(new descricaoo(ibanco, codigo, descricaobol, qtde));
        }
        public IBanco Banco { get; set; }
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public int QuantidadeDias { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preste atenção no que está fazendo. Entra no construtor `descricaoo`, dentro dele você cria uma lista e adiciona um item nela. Este item é criado chamando um novo objeto desta mesma classe. Ou seja, vai chamar este construtor de novo. O que acontece quando o chama? Ele chamará este construtor mais uma vez. E assim vai indefinidamente. Até que a [memória reservada para alocar as variáveis locais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) não tem mais espaço e estoura.

Sua lógica está muito errada. Repense o problema e veja como tem que criar esta classe. Não posso ajudar muito sem saber o problema, mas dá para perceber que há vários problemas, não só no construtor, mas em toda a classe. Talvez em toda a aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora eu fiz um if :"if (desci!=null)", como eu saio da classe se a lista desci nao for nula?

Comment: Só com isto não tem como ajudar. Faça uma pergunta detalhando o que fez, qual é o problema e o que deveria acontecer. Mas já adianto que não se sai da classe.

Comment: Estou fazendo um sistema para emitir boleto. Precisa ser passado essas informações para a interface IInstrucao e depois ser passada para as variáveis html para emitir o boleto. Tem uma função que pega os dados do banco, e dessa função eu mando as informações por parâmetro para a classe descricaoo, e esses dados serão adicionados numa lista do tipo IInstrucao e assim serem passados para as variáveis do boleto.